# Proof help: $F$ is infinite, then a vector space $V$ is not the union of finitely many proper subspaces of $V.$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove: If a field $F$ is infinite, then a vector space $V$ is not the union of finitely many proper subspaces of $V.$

I am first trying to understand this problem by looking at the case of just two subspaces. Suppose $V= W_1 \cup W_2$ with $W_1, W_2 \subset V$. There exists $x \in W_1$ such that $x \not \in W_2$ because otherwise $W_1 \subset W_2$ and so $V=W_2$, contradicting the assumption that $W_2$ is a proper subspace. Likewise, there exists $y \in W_2$ such that $y \not \in W_1$. Now, $x+y \in V$, so $x+y \in W_1$ or $x+y \in W_2$. WLOG suppose $x+y \in W_1$. Then, there is a $w \in W_1$ such that $x+y=w$. But then $y=w-x \in W_1$, which contradicts $y \not \in W_1$.

Now notice that I did not conclude that $F$ must be finite. In fact, I have(most likely incorreclty) proven that a vector space over any field (not just infinite fields)is not the union of two proper subspaces. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Please do not completely give away the proof.

Comment: Your result is fine and standard- the union of two subspaces is a subspace only if one contains the other.

Comment: @Seeker then where do I go wrong in my proof?

Comment: It is relevant. And you'll use basically the same strategy in the general case. Suppose $V = \cup_{i \leq n} V_i$ all proper subspaces. For simplicity we can assume none of them is contained in the union of the remaining. Then take $x \in V_1$, and $y \in \cup_{2 \leq i}V_i$. Then consider the subspace $x + Fy$. What is the size of each $x+Fy \cap V_i$ and thus what is the size of $|x+Fy|$ itself? What does this tell you about the size of $F$?

Comment: @Seeker The problem is about infinite field $F$.

Comment: That's what I am trying to understand. My proof must be invalid because I conclude that V is not the union of two subspaces for any field. but I can't see what is wrong with it...

Comment: That should be $y+Fx$ above not $x +Fy$

Comment: @cfre It's true that for any field $F$, if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$, then $W_1 \cup W_2$ is also a subspace of $V$ if and only if $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ or $W_2 \subseteq W_1$. So your proof for two subspaces doesn't have any issue and there's no need to use infiniteness of $F$.

Comment: @Seeker I say that there exists $x \in W_1$ such that $x \not \in W_2$ becuase if this is not the case then for all $x \in W_1$ we have $x \in W_2$ and so $W_1$ is a subset of $W_2$... and $V$ is the union of these two susbets, so $V= W_2$ contradicitng the fact that $W_2$ is a proper subset.

Comment: @Seeker The statement *"there exists $x \in W_1$ such that $x \not\in W_2$"* is true, because "otherwise", for all $x \in W_1$ we have $x \in W_2$, that means $W_1 \subseteq W_2$, which implies $V = W_1 \cup W_2 = W_2$. A contradiction.

Comment: @on1921379 oh yeah. my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I might as well make it into a proper answer/hint.

Suppose $V = \cup_{i \leq n}V_i$ where the $V_i$ are proper subspaces. We can assume that $V_j \subsetneq \cup_{i \neq j}V_i$ for all $i$ (otherwise $V_j$ would  just be redundant anyway).

Now take $x \in V_1$ and $y \in \cup_{2 \leq i}V_i$ such that $x \not \in \cup_{i\geq 2}V_i$ and $y \not \in V_1$.

Now consider the subspace $\{y + rx: r \in F\} =: W$.

Notice that $W \cap V_1 = \emptyset$.

And $|W \cap V_i| \leq 1$ for every $i \geq 2$ (why?)

Thus since $y+Fx = \cup_{i\leq n} V_i \cap (y+Fx)$ this means that $|y+Fx| \leq n-1$. But $|y+Fx| = |F|$ which contradicts infiniteness.

Comment: I doubt that $W$ would be a subspace... If $y + rx = o$ for some $r \in F$, then $y = -rx$ which means $y \in V_1$. Also, I can't prove that for any $\lambda \in F$ and any $y + rx \in W$, we have $\lambda(y + rx) \in W$.